# 16.04 how to enable cors in nginx

Tags: 16.04, nginx

does anyone know how to enable the Allow-Access-Control-Origin in nginx?

I'm using vanilla JavaScript to send the GET Request.

I've been searching on the web and trying their config for nginx but it seems all of those doesn't work.

I'm trying to get a response from a certain url.
I've tried using Chrome's CORS plugin.
My JavaScript is working with the correct response.

BUT I need it to run on the server though with Allow-Access-Control-Origin enabled

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think you're having a CORS issue?

This is a very open configuration and should be placed inside the **server** block.  You should fine-tune it once you're live:

```
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS";
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*";
```

Comment: I'm getting it from a different domain using JavaScript.
I've tried a lot of things even setting cors in JavaScript, JSONP and etc still no luck.
only the Chrome CORS Plugin works.

Comment: I'm still getting an error on my local
"Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://mydomain.app' is therefore not allowed access."